# Difficulty in Duplicating showed behaviour with different markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to duplicate following behaviour of player: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html I was able to do everything besides this bit (You can check page source for full code)

```
// Setup the player to autoplay the next track
        var a = audiojs.createAll({
          trackEnded: function() {
            var next = $('ol li.playing').next();
            if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
            next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
            audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
            audio.play();
          }
        });
```

A demo page has following structure:

```
<ol> 
  <li class="playing">
    <a href="#" data-src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/audiojs/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a>
  </li>

  <li class="playing">
    <a href="#" data-src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/audiojs/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a>
  </li>

  <li class="playing">
    <a href="#" data-src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/audiojs/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a>
  </li>

  <!-- Etc -->
</ol>
```

However my page has the following structure:

```
<div class="main">
  <article class="article>

    <!-- .. -->
    <div class="article-footer>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="article-play" href="#" data-src="http://somesongurl.com/file.mp3"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </article>
</div>
```

Therefore inside each article there is anchor tag with class article-play, these act same as anchor tags in demo page inside `<ol>` So I want to auto play each anchor tag, the issue is that they are not inside `<ol>` but in actual separate articles. I tried this:

```
          // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
          var a = audiojs.createAll({
          trackEnded: function() {
              var next = $('.main a.playing').next();
              if (!next.length) next = $('.main a.article-play').first();
              next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
              audio.load($('.article-play', next).attr('data-src'));
              audio.play();
          }
      });
```

But it doesn't work, once song finishes playing and is supposed to switch to next one src inside audio tag becomes `src="undefined"` I'm new to jQuery and possibly don't understand how to implement correct structure, so I'm asking community for help.

**EDIT** There are other list element with anchor tags inside them inside each .article-footer div. Therefore src for the player needs to be looked up specifically from anchor with class of .article-play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next()` is getting the next sibling of an element. In your code you are trying to get the next sibling of the anchor tag, but in one list item there is only one anchor element. You can fix this issue adding the 'playing' class to the list items instead of the anchor tags, and then your player should work as expected.

**So instead of this:**

```
var next = $('.main a.playing').next();
```

**Use this:**

```
var next = $('.main li.playing').next();
```

So that the list items will get the 'playing' class, and you will be able to access the next list item.

jQuery Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/next/